# Пересылка с помощью бота сообщения/поста из группы в группу в Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Всем доброго времени суток!
Суть вопроса, на данный момент бот из одной группы Telegram пересылает сообщения в другую группу по ключевому слову. Пересылает бот только текст, если в сообщение появляется любой приложенный файл то сообщение не пересылается.

1. Возможно ли реализовать пересылку сообщения как в оригинальном чате, со всеми вложениями?
2. В случае если первый вариант не реализовать совсем, то хотя бы пост "текст с фото"?
   Желателен первый вариант, буду благодарен помощи.

```
    import telebot
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('##################')
    
    chatID = ##############
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Для помощи наберите команду /help и будет помощь')
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут сообщение о помощи')
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def all_messages(message):
        if 'ключевое слово' in message.text.lower():
            bot.forward_message(chatID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у медиа-файлов за текст отвечает параметр `caption`. Реализовать это можно так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
def all_media_messages(message):
    if message.caption is not None and 'ключевое слово' in message.caption.lower():
        bot.forward_message(chatID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: да, действительно это работает, благодарю. Единственная проблема, в том, что теперь при загрузке любого медиафайла программа крашится. Но в случае если загружать медиафайл с ключевым словом, то все стабильно работает. Простые текстовые сообщения с ключевым словом так же перестал отправлять, возможно отдельным блоком конечно получится реализовать, но не точно

Comment: В каком смысле крашится? В логи смотрели?

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробоуйте сейчас

Comment: Да, все отлично! Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь, + в карму однозначно! Добавил блок для текста, теперь и текст отправляет и медиа.

Comment: Не за что, был рад помочь :)